# How to make SSH go directly to specific directory?

Tags: ssh, directory

when you do an "ssh second_machine" you are able to connect to second_machine on your home directory

But usually i am working in my_machine in directory with very long path, and i want to connect to second_machine and move to my working directory right away. So everytime i have to:

> ssh second_machine
>   cd /very/long/path/to/directory/

Is there a way to make it automatic ?? ( ssh automatically go to the desired directory )

Comment: this might have better responses on the sister site, http://superuser.com/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706608

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/167416/how-can-i-automatically-change-directory-on-ssh-login

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should work for you

```
ssh  -t second_machine "cd /very/long/path/to/directory/; bash"
```

Assumes you're wanting to run bash, substitute for a different shell if required.

Comment: That meets the specifications !! Thanks :)

Comment: And this works because: 1) ssh starts a shell, in the homedir. 2) That shell executes the commands passed. 3) The first command (a shell command, `cd`) changes the cwd in that shell. 4) The second command, `bash` starts a new shell, which inherits the `cwd` from the parent process (the original shell started by ssh)

Comment: There must be a way to tell `ssh` directly to change the cwd before running the initial shell, skipping lots of steps.

Answer (score 10):

To make it permanent, use `RemoteCommand` in your `~/.ssh/config` file, e.g.

```
Host myhost
  HostName IP
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  RemoteCommand cd /path/to/directory; $SHELL -il
```

Related:

- [SSH Config File Alias To Get To a Directory On Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14387872/55075)
- [How can I automatically change directory on ssh login?](https://serverfault.com/q/167416/130437)
- [Run a remote command using ssh config file](https://superuser.com/q/124101/87805)

Comment: That solves (and quotes cause issues on `RemoteCommand`!), but it's only available after SSH 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the one I'm using. Make an alias as the one below.

```
alias ssh 'ssh -t \!* "cd $PWD; csh"'
```

(here, csh could also be replaced by bash)

This brings you directly to the 'current' path on the other machine.
The usage would be like [$] ssh some machine
However, I find that it works slow. So, I'm looking for an alternative.