# SSH into Specified Directory by Default?

Tags: ssh, debian

By default, when SSH'ing into a client I am automatically placed into /home/marco/ but instead I would like to be placed into /something/other. I would prefer to keep my home directory where it is, but I would like to be automatically routed to /something/other/

Is this possible?

*The client runs Debian 5.04

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593570

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the command in the ssh to change the directory at the same time you login:

```
ssh -t localhost "cd /tmp ; bash"
```

You might get what you want after an alias:

```
alias ssh-tmp='ssh -t localhost "cd /tmp ; bash"'
```

So command *'ssh-tmp'* will put you directly in the tmp directory.