# SSH config file paragraph to open a specific directory on remote server

Tags: ssh, alias, config

Is there a way to specifically ssh into a particular directory in remote location, **specifically using the local ssh config file** (not terminal)? Something like `Dir` option in the paragraph below, for example,

```
    Host remote_dir
       Hostname remote_server
       User username
       Dir path/to/remote_dir/
```

So, if I, ssh using the Host value from above paragraph,

```sh
ssh remote_dir
```

Then, I would like to be logged in and the terminal to be ready for me at `path/to/remote_dir/` of the remote server,

```sh
username@remote_server: path/to/remote_dir/ > pwd
/home/username/path/to/remote_dir/
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593570/how-to-make-ssh-go-directly-to-specific-directory?rq=1

Comment: no it isn't, I want to know how to do it in an ssh Config file. I think thats clear in the question.

Comment: understand, I missed that. However, the same question has been asked on serverfault (see my answer). That may be helpful, as they stumpled upon the same mistake as me (`LocalCommand` in `~/.ssh/config` seems to be the wrong way as it is not executed on the remote machine).

Answer (score 24):

In this post [on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/167416/change-directory-automatically-on-ssh-login), they say you can't do it all through the ssh config file. But you can do it with the ssh config and your .bash_profile or whatever the terminal nerds call it. 
in the ssh config file add

```
Host dev
  Hostname server.com
  User joe
```

then in your .bash_profile add an alias

```
alias domain1="ssh dev -t 'cd domains/domain1; bash'"
```

Here the `dev` refers to what you set up in the config file.

In the Terminal, just type `domain1`, you will be asked to put in your password and will go straight to the directory. Make a new alias for all your domains and it will make logging in to each one super easy.

Comment: What should I put instead of `domains/domain1;`? `github.com/CompanyName`?

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at
https://serverfault.com/questions/167416/change-directory-automatically-on-ssh-login

This is the [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/167439/151221):

> `LocalCommand` isn't what you want, anyway.  That's run on *your* machine.  You want `RemoteCommand`.  Something like this worked for me:

```sh
  Host example.net
  RemoteCommand cd / && exec bash --login
  RequestTTY yes
```

---

(Old answer) For a similar use case, `ssh -t` is also an option:

```
ssh server -t "cd /my/remote/directory; bash --login"
```

It is not the same, as it does not use ssh config. But you can define an alias for the command and end up with a similar effect.

Comment: The answer has been edited in the referenced serverfault post. The new accepted answer answers this question. https://serverfault.com/a/167439/469428

Comment: @MitaliCyrus Thanks, I updated my copy of the answer. Still leaving the old answer (slightly edited) below, as it might be useful if the effect does not have to come through ssh config.