# SSH to remote server node and change directory

Tags: ssh

I wanted to achieve the following task:

step 1: ssh to the remote server

step 2: ssh to a node connected to that server

step 3: change to a particulat directory of that node

I was looking for a ssh one liner and issued the following command

```
ssh -t -t user@remote.server "ssh node; cd /my/directory/"
```

However, the last cd command did not work. I am still in my home
directory of the node in remote server. I tried to remove the ";" part,
and issued the following one liner:

```
ssh -t -t user@remote.server "ssh node cd /my/directory/"
```

No success. The message was "Connection to remote.server closed"

I was wondering whether it is possible to achieve this task
using an ssh one liner.

Thanking you in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close and could have played around a little bit more.
[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387872/ssh-config-file-alias-to-get-to-a-directory-on-server) helped, and apparently the following syntax worked:

```
ssh -t user@remote.server "ssh -t node 'cd /my/directory/ ; bash'"
```

However, I do not understand the role of the "bash" part.